# Using the Rails gem 'Mailboxer' and the sender_id is always zero

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, mailboxer

Just integrated Mailboxer and I'm running into one problem. When I send a new message the `sender_id` in the `mailboxer_notifications` table is always zero instead of the id of the sender.

I'm using the friendly_id gem for usernames and I think this is where the problem is but I cant find out how to fix it (if it even is the problem).

messages/new.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, "New Message") %>

<%= form_tag user_messages_path, method: :post do %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag 'message[subject]', 'Subject' %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'message[subject]', nil, class: 'form-control', required: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag 'message[body]', 'Message' %>
    <%= text_area_tag 'message[body]', nil, cols: 3, class: 'form-control', required: true %>
  </div>


<div class="form-group">
  <%= label_tag 'recipients', 'Choose recipients' %>
  <%= select_tag 'recipients', recipients_options(@chosen_recipient), multiple: true, class: 'form-control chosen-it' %>
</div>

  <%= submit_tag 'Send', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

messages_controller.rb

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user

  def new
    @user = current_user
    @chosen_recipient = User.find_by(id: params[:to].to_i) if params[:to]
  end

  def create
    @user = current_user
    recipients = User.where(id: params['recipients'])
    conversation = current_user.send_message(recipients, params[:message][:body], params[:message][:subject]).conversation
    flash[:success] = "Message has been sent!"
    redirect_to user_conversation_path(@user, conversation)
  end

  private

  def authenticate_user
    unless ((current_user.id = params[:user_id]) unless current_user.nil?)
      flash[:error] = 'Looks like your not supposed to be there'
      redirect_to login_path
    end
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :users do
  resources :conversations, only: [:index, :show, :destroy] do
    member do
      post :reply
      post :restore
      delete :empty_trash
      post :mark_as_read
    end
  end
  resources :messages, only: [:new, :create]
end
```

I mostly followed [this tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/messaging-rails-mailboxer/) when integrating the gem. I have no idea why it isn't saving the user id properly when they send a new message.

**update**
The reason I suspect friendly_id is causing it so save the `sender_id` as 0 is because when I don't use friendly id in the url e.g. users/1/messages/new it works fine but users/example-user/messages/new it doesn't save the user id when creating a new message

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if I follow your `authenticate_user` implementation:

```
def authenticate_user
  unless ((current_user.id = params[:user_id]) unless current_user.nil?)
    flash[:error] = 'Looks like your not supposed to be there'
    redirect_to login_path
  end
end
```

You may want to simplify it.

If you are trying to compare `current_user.id` to `params[:user_id]`, you need to use `current_user.id == params[:user_id]`, not `current_user.id = params[:user_id]`. Its `==`, not `=`.

Comment: Thanks adding the `==` helped but I now get the error `Couldn't find Mailboxer::Conversation with 'id'=2 [WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" = 'Mailboxer::Message' AND "mailboxer_receipts"."receiver_id" = ? AND "mailboxer_receipts"."receiver_type" = ?]` when I send a message