# Rendering error messages not working on just one page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

I can't get error messages to display on this page. They display fine for any other page but not this one

mod_approval.index.html.erb

```
<%  @check_category.each do |category| %>

 <%= form_for([@guide, Guide.friendly.find(@guide.id).categories.new], url: guide_mod_panel_approve_category_path, method: :post) do |f| %>
       <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
       <%= hidden_field_tag :check_id, category.id %>
       <%= f.hidden_field :name, :value => category.name %>
       <%= f.submit "Approve"  %>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

mod_approval_controller

```
def mod_add_category

    @guide          = Guide.friendly.find(params[:guide_id])
    @check_category = CheckCategory.where(guide_id: @guide.id).all
    @category       = Guide.friendly.find(@guide.id).categories.new(category_params)

      if @category.save 

     flash[:success] = "Game category added succesfully!"
     redirect_to guide_mod_panel_mod_approval_index_path(@guide)
  else
     render 'mod_approval/index'
  end

end
```

routes

```
match '/guides/:guide_id/mod-panel/approve/category' => 'mod_approval#mod_add_category', :via => :post, as: :guide_mod_panel_approve_category
match '/guides/:guide_id/mod-panel/approve' => 'mod_approval#index', :via => :get, as: :guide_mod_panel_mod_approval_index
```

Not too sure why they aren't rendering I tried changing `<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>` to  `<%= render partial: 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>` but that gives the error

```
undefined local variable or method `object' for #<#<Class:0x007ffdbcd1c3a8>:0x007ffdbcbdd320>
```

on this line `<% if object.errors.any? %>`

This error rendering setup was made from Michael Hartls rails tutorial and as I said I works fine for every other form but this one.

Comment: What does a form that works look like?

Comment: @muistooshort <%= form_for([@category, @category_item], url: category_items_create_path) do |f| %>
   <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

   <%= f.label :name, "Name" %>
   <%= f.text_field :name %>

   <%= f.submit "Next"  %>
<% end %>

Comment: And you're certain that there are errors to display when the partial doesn't render?

Comment: @muistooshort yea when I submit a duplicate name no errors show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that when you render the form, you instantiate a new Category:

```
form_for([@guide, Guide.friendly.find(@guide.id).categories.new],
```

You need to give `form_for` the Category instance that has the errors (`@category` from your controller). So I would change your form to this:

```
form_for([@guide, @category],
```

And then in your `#new` method make sure you set it up:

```
@category = @guide.categories.build
```

Comment: Thanks. There was originally a reason why I wasn't using `@category` but I fixed it and forgot to put `@category` back (or though it wasn't going to cause nay harm if I left it). Hate to do this but can you checkout my other question if you cant or don't know it its fine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36109532/using-the-rails-gem-mailboxer-and-the-sender-id-is-always-zero

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Mailboxer, and your code never mentions a `sender_id`. :-)